# Finding ancestor who was World War 1 Polish soldier?

Tags: military-records, poland, world-war-1

I am trying to find my great-grandfather, who was a Polish soldier in World War 1.

He supposedly came from a noble family (I am from Slovenia), so I suppose he fought on the Austrian Italian front.

His daughter was my grandmother who was born in 1918.

My great grandfather left then (1917 probably) and went to Poland where he died or was killed (I don't know if in battle or due to other causes) probably between 1918 and 1920, since he intended to return.

My grandmother was born in Jarenina (small village in Slovenia) and she didn't know him, so the problem is that she was an illegitimate child and we know nothing else about him.

Is there any chance I can find anything about him or who he was?

Comment: A lot of questions come to my mind: Do you know his name? By "Poland" you mean the [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Poland_(1917%E2%80%9318)](Kingdom of Poland), as an independent Polish state was recreated in 1918? Do you have any pictures of him? Where are your information coming from, oral history or do you also have some documents? What is stated in your grandmother’s birth certificate?

Comment: no i dont know his name unfortunatly and yes those are oral sources and by poland i mean he was of polish ethnicity so he was somewhere from polish ethnic territory that was during wwi split between russia germany and austria hungary all of my sources come from my grandmothers sister

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: It may be a long shot but have you considered having an autosomal DNA test (e.g. AncestryDNA).  If second or third cousin strength matches show up that you cannot otherwise explain then this great grandfather may be their source.